# jQuery Loading in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, loading

I have built an application where client-side scripting is with JS & jQuery and server-side functions are by a java based application. The web page works like a charm in my system in all the browsers, however, when I deploy it on a different system with the same IE version, I see strange loading effects.

Such as,

the loading image during AJAX call doesnt get displayed "alive" until the response is received. This is stuck and gif becomes jpeg somewhere during its course;
the ajax resposne is appended to the form at the bottom of the same page , in a new div, which works as expected in my system on IE9, FF20, CHR27. This doesnt work on a different system where only  IE is installed and cannot afford for other browsers;

I had tried reseting browsers settings, with no luck. I also tried doing something with developer tools in IE9, [dont know what it is exactly, maybe something to do with debugging!] after which it displayed the results in expected form only for that session.

Can someone help me understand what change should I imply on the new system's browser to get this working?

thank you

EDITED:

alright, because this code worked in the same version of IE on one system, I was hoping that there might not be a problem with code. But here is the piece of code, performing the task narrated above:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $('#checkmark').hide();

    var selectionModule = $("#currentSelectedValue").text();
    var channelName;
    var dataString = 'selection='+ selectionModule;

    if(selectionModule == 'About the APP!') 
    {
        $('#result_area').empty();
        $('#result_area').css('marginLeft', '250px');
        $('#result_area').css('marginRight', '250px');
        $('#result_area').load('read-me.html');

    }
    else if((selectionModule == 'Deployed Channels List') || (selectionModule == 'System pFlows'))
    {
        $('#result_area').empty();
        $('#result_area').css('marginLeft', '0px');
        $('#result_area').css('marginRight', '0px');

        channelName = 'NA';
        dataString += '&channelName=' + channelName;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:9123/",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend : function(){
                $('#checkmark1').show(); },
            success: function(result) {

                $('#result_area').html("<div id='message' style='display: table;'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>"+selectionModule+":</h2>")
                $('#message').append("<p>"+result+"</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $('#checkmark1').hide();
                    $('#checkmark').show();
                });

            }
        });
    } 
    else if(selectionModule != 'Deployed Channels List')
    {

        $('#result_area').empty();
        $('#result_area').css('marginLeft', '0px');
        $('#result_area').css('marginRight', '0px');

        channelName = $("#cntext").val();
        dataString += '&channelName=' + channelName;
        //console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:9123/",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend : function(){
                $('#checkmark1').show(); },
            success: function(result) {

                $('#result_area').html("<div id='message' style='display: table;'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>"+selectionModule+" for Channel "+channelName+":</h2>")
                $('#message').append("<p>"+result+"</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $('#checkmark1').hide();
                    $('#checkmark').show();
                });

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Add a semicolon on line 45. Silly answer? Sure, but since you've shown no code, it's as good as any.

Comment: Even if there's no problem with the code, we need to see it to know what browser issues it might run into. But I'm not sure how a browser could turn a GIF into JPEG.

Comment: GIF to JPEG conversion was my way of explaining that the GIF image did not behave like a GIF but was stuck in course of waiting for an AJAX response. It does not literally mean that a GIF in a web page is turned into a JPEG.

Comment: Your problem is confusing enough, don't make it worse with unclear descriptions of the problem. What part of the code relates to the image with the problem -- `#checkmark1`?

Comment: Is one of the IE9's running in Compatibility Mode?

Comment: yupp #checkmark1 is the loading image that gets frozen. None of the IE instances are on c-mode. Enabling c-mdoe gets a disastrous output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some investigation, I noticed that I have used Console.log(); at one location in the code, which was undefined for IE. After adding the following line to the top of my the HTML, the AJAX response nows gets displayed in the div that is at the bottom of the form and does not get disaplyed on a new page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>
```

This just resolves one of the two issues reported. The other one with reference to GIF not animated is still a problem in IE9 on a specific machine. Strangely enough, it works perfectly on another system's IE9. I'll publish any worthy findings here.

Thanks for the help, so far.

Comment: If all that's missing is GIF animation, maybe **Play animations in webpages** in Internet Options is unchecked.

Comment: well done my friend! That was indeed disabled. This works perfectly now! Thank you. Appreciate it. +1 for rightly suspecting it.